# Approximating/Sorting groups of dates into buckets

Tags: javascript, performance, datetime, sorting, d3.js

I'm working on a directed study project with a professor of mine helping him build out a Django based website. The website is a historical account of the people, events, projects, and organization in the computer graphics industry.

Since the beginning of the project (way before I started working on it) my professor has had the idea of creating a timeline of everything that has been entered into the site. The original team came up with this design.

[image: timeline prototype image]

I worked on the project for all of last semester and started on building out this timeline feature around the middle of December. Since then I've continued to work on it till now, but on and off. I feel like that has attributed to some crappy code since I've walked into it without thinking about it for a week or two a number of times now.

Anyway, I've put together a JSFiddle of the current state of the project **[over here](http://jsfiddle.net/GowGuy47/9j98E/3/)**, which I'm hoping to get some advice and feedback on.

Here is the main JavaScript file:

```
/* 
* @Author: Gowiem
* @Date:   2013-12-17 14:21:17
*/

var Hist = Hist || {};

// Timeline Utils
//////////////////
Hist.TLUtils = (function() {
  var timeConversions = { "year": 31557600000,
                          "month": 2628000000,
                          "day":     86400000 };

  // Note: The following method uses memoization so it doesn't need to recalculate
  // the range for a year/mod pair that it has already seen. This is definitely
  // overkill, but I felt like doing this. :)
  var rangeMemo = {};
  var pubBuildRange = function(year, mod) {
    var result = rangeMemo[year],
        halfMod,
        remainder,
        rangeBegin,
        rangeEnd;
    // If we haven't seen the given year yet then continue and find the range.
    if (!result) {
      remainder = year % mod;
      halfMod = mod / 2;

      // Find the rangeBegin by using the remainder to determine if we need to start at xxx5 or xxx0
      rangeBegin = remainder <= halfMod ? year - remainder : year - remainder + halfMod;
      rangeEnd = rangeBegin + halfMod;

      result = Hist.TLO.range(moment(rangeBegin, 'YYYY').valueOf(), moment(rangeEnd, 'YYYY').valueOf());

      // Memoize the result so we don't have to do this again.
      rangeMemo[year + "|" + mod] = result;
    }

    return result;
  }

  // TODO: Memoize same as above
  var pubBuildMonthRange = function(date, numberOfMonths) {
    var monthDate = moment(date).startOf('month');

    rangeBegin = monthDate.clone().subtract('months', numberOfMonths);
    rangeEnd = monthDate.clone().add('months', numberOfMonths);
    result = Hist.TLO.range(rangeBegin.valueOf(), rangeEnd.valueOf());

    return result;
  }

  var pubConvertTime = function(howMany, type) {
    if (timeConversions.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
      return howMany * timeConversions[type];
    } else {
      console.assert(false, "Hist.TLUtils.convertTime was given unknown type: ", type);
    }
  }

  var pubRoundToDecade = function(date, shouldFloor) {
    var year = date.getFullYear(),
        remainder = year % 10,
        roundedYear = shouldFloor ? (year - remainder) - 10 : (year - remainder) + 10,
        roundedDate = new Date(date.getTime()).setFullYear(roundedYear);
    return roundedDate;
  }

  var pubGenerateRandomId = function() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
               .toString(16)
               .substring(1);
  }

  return {
    buildRange: pubBuildRange,
    roundToDecade: pubRoundToDecade,
    convertTime: pubConvertTime,
    buildMonthRange: pubBuildMonthRange,
    generateRandomId: pubGenerateRandomId
  }
})();

// Timeline Objects
////////////////////
Hist.TLO = Hist.TLO || {};
Hist.TLO.range = function(begin, end) {
  var rangeObject = {},
      beginEpoch  = begin,
      endEpoch    = end,
      begin       = new Date(begin),
      end         = new Date(end),
      differenceInYears = end.getYear() - begin.getYear();

  var halfWayDate = function() {
    return new Date(beginEpoch + ((endEpoch - beginEpoch)/2));
  }

  var toString = function() {
    return "Range - begin: " + this.begin.toString() + " end: " + this.end.toString() + " halfWayDate: " + this.halfWayDate().toString();
  }

  // Fields
  rangeObject.begin = begin;
  rangeObject.end   = end;
  rangeObject.differenceInYears = differenceInYears;

  // Methods
  rangeObject.halfWayDate = halfWayDate;
  rangeObject.toString = toString;

  return rangeObject;
}

// Our Collection of Point Objects
Hist.TLO.pointCollection = function(pages) {
  var collection = {},
      allPoints = [],
      current = [],
      pointPositions = {},
      point,
      // Util Aliases
      buildRange      = Hist.TLUtils.buildRange,
      buildMonthRange = Hist.TLUtils.buildMonthRange,
      roundToDecade   = Hist.TLUtils.roundToDecade,
      // TLO Aliases
      timelinePoint   = Hist.TLO.timelinePoint,
      multiPoint      = Hist.TLO.multiPoint;


  // Loop through the given pages and construct our timeline points
  pages.forEach(function(page, idx) {
    point = timelinePoint(page);
    if (point.isValid()) {
      allPoints.push(point);
      current.push(point);
    }
  });

  // Iterates through the timeline points to find their x and y positions
  // and stores them in pointPositions for later use. 
  // Returns { point.id => { x: xPos, y: yPos }, ... }
  var buildPointPositions = function(timelineRange) {
    var pointsDup = this.current.clone(),
        self = this,
        count,
        xPos,
        pointYear,
        range,
        i;

    this.current.forEach(function(point, outerIndex) {
      count = 0;
      xPos = null;

      // Iterate through the dups to find the range that this point belongs in
      // and how many other points are in that same range. This determined xPos
      // which is the approximate year for the point and the count which is how
      // high we should stack the point.
      pointsDup.forEach(function(p, innerIndex) {
        pointYear = point.date.year();

        // Possible ranges:
        // 80+ years: buckets of 5 years
        // 30+ years: buckets of 4 years
        // 20+ years: Buckets of 2 years
        // 10+ years: Buckets of 1 year
        // 4+  years: Buckets of 4 months
        // 4-  years: No Range, Only stack if in same month
        if (timelineRange.differenceInYears >= 80) {
          range = buildRange(p.date.year(), 10);
          // console.log("=========== range is 80+");
        } else if (timelineRange.differenceInYears >= 30) {
          // console.log("=========== range is 30+");
          range = buildRange(p.date.year(), 8);
        } else if (timelineRange.differenceInYears >= 20) {
          // console.log("=========== range is 20+");
          range = buildRange(p.date.year(), 4);
        } else if (timelineRange.differenceInYears >= 10) {
          // console.log("=========== range is 10+");
          range = buildMonthRange(p.date, 6);
        } else if (timelineRange.differenceInYears >= 4) {
          // console.log("=========== range is 4+");
          range = buildMonthRange(p.date, 2);
        } else {
          // console.log("=========== range is 4-");
          range = null;
        }

        // Check if point's date is within the range created by p
        if (range && point.withinRange(range)) {
          xPos = range.halfWayDate();
          if (point.id !== p.id) {
            count += 1;
          }
        } else if (point.isSameMonthAsPoint(p) && point.id !== p.id) {
          xPos = p.date;
          count += 1;
        }



      }); // End pointsDup.forEach

      // Otherwise it stands alone and we should set the xPos to it's actual
      // position.
      if (!xPos) {
        xPos = point.date;
      }

      // Remove the current point from pointsDup
      pointsDup = hidePointWithId(point.id, pointsDup);

      // Set the x and y position of the current point
      self.pointPositions[point.id] = { 'x': xPos, 'y': count }
    });
  }

  var clearPointPositions = function() {
    this.pointPositions = {};
  }

  // TODO: Probably a smarter way of making this reusable for both 'this.current'
  // and the pointsDup in buildPointPosn. Can't think of it now. 
  var hidePointWithId = function(pId, points) {
    var pointId = parseInt(pId), 
        points = points || this.current;
    return points.filter(function(p) {
      return pointId !== p.id;
    });
  }

  var filterInRange = function(range) {
    this.current = this.allPoints.filter(function(point, idx) {
      return point.withinRange(range);
    });
  }

  var addMultiPoints = function(yearsToAdd) {
    var self = this,
        mPoint;

    yearsToAdd = yearsToAdd.unique();
    yearsToAdd.forEach(function(year, idx) {
      mPoint = multiPoint(year);
      self.current.push(mPoint);
      self.pointPositions[mPoint.id] = { x: year, y: Hist.TL.config.maxOfStacked };
    });
  }

  var replaceMaxStacked = function() {
    var yearsToAddMultiPoint = [],
        positionKeys = Object.keys(this.pointPositions),
        self = this,
        xPos,
        yPos;

    positionKeys.forEach(function(pId, idx) {
      xPos = self.pointPositions[pId]['x'];
      yPos = self.pointPositions[pId]['y'];

      if (yPos >= Hist.TL.config.maxOfStacked) {
        yearsToAddMultiPoint.push(xPos);
        self.current = self.hidePointWithId(pId);
      }
    });

    // Now that we've remove the points which were stacked too high we can 
    // add back the multiPoints in their place.
    this.addMultiPoints(yearsToAddMultiPoint);
  }

  // Fields
  collection.allPoints = allPoints;
  collection.current = current;
  collection.pointPositions = pointPositions;

  // Methods
  collection.buildPointPositions = buildPointPositions;
  collection.clearPointPositions = clearPointPositions;
  collection.filterInRange = filterInRange;
  collection.hidePointWithId = hidePointWithId;
  collection.replaceMaxStacked = replaceMaxStacked;
  collection.addMultiPoints = addMultiPoints;

  return collection;
}

// Our Point object
Hist.TLO.timelinePoint = function(page) {
  var point = {};

  // This is the kind of code you have to write when people use a table to 
  // represent a simple string. Seriously though, da fuq!
  // TODO: I can do this simpler with an array.. doh. 
  var findType = function(categoryId) {
    switch (categoryId) {
      case 1:
        return 'person';
      case 2:
        return 'project';
      case 3:
        return 'organization';
      case 4:
        return 'event';
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  point.id = page['pk'];
  point.name = page['fields']['name'] || page['name'];
  point.vanityUrl = page['fields']['vanity_url'] || page['vanityUrl'];
  point.description = page['fields']['description'] || page['description'];
  point.date = moment(page['fields']['date_established']) || moment();
  point.type = findType(page['fields']['type']) || page['type'];
  point.pointImage = "/static/img/timeline/" + point.type + "-button.png";

  var toString = function() {
    return "Point -> id: " + this.id + " name: " + this.name + " date: " + this.date.format('l') + " type: " + this.type;
  }

  var isValid = function() {
    return this.type != null && !!page['fields']['date_established'];
  }

  var withinRange = function(range) {
    return this.date.isAfter(range.begin) && this.date.isBefore(range.end)
                                          || this.date.isSame(range.begin)
                                          || this.date.isSame(range.end);
  }

  var isSameMonthAsPoint = function(point) {
    return this.date.isSame(point.date, 'year') && this.date.isSame(point.date, 'month');
  }

  var isSameDayAsPoint = function(point) {
    return this.date.isSame(point.date, 'year') && this.date.isSame(point.date, 'month') && this.date.isSame(point.date, 'day');
  }

  point.toString = toString;
  point.isValid  = isValid;
  point.withinRange = withinRange;
  point.isSameMonthAsPoint = isSameMonthAsPoint;
  point.isSameDayAsPoint = isSameDayAsPoint;

  return point;
}

Hist.TLO.multiPoint = function(year) {
  var pointDefaults = { name: "Multiple Available", vanityUrl: null,
                        description: "Multiple Available", type: 'multi',
                        fields: {} },
      point = Hist.TLO.timelinePoint(pointDefaults);

  point.id = Hist.TLUtils.generateRandomId();
  point.date = moment(new Date(year, 5));

  return point;
}

// Timeline
////////////
Hist.TL = (function() {
  var margin = {top: 90, right: 30, bottom: 90, left: 30},
      width = 960,
      height = 300,
      maxOfStacked = 4,
      pointSize = 25,
      yPosMargin = 30,
      pointClicked = false,
      timelinePoints,
      brush,
      xAxis,
      xScale,
      beginning,
      ending,
      chart,
      // Alias our TimelineUtils methods
      buildRange      = Hist.TLUtils.buildRange,
      buildMonthRange = Hist.TLUtils.buildMonthRange,
      roundToDecade   = Hist.TLUtils.roundToDecade,
      // Alias our Timeline Objects
      pointCollection = Hist.TLO.pointCollection,
      timelinePoint   = Hist.TLO.timelinePoint,
      multiPoint      = Hist.TLO.multiPoint;



  var initD3Chart = function() {
    var jsDates = timelinePoints.current.map(function(p) { return p.date.toDate(); });

    beginning   = roundToDecade(d3.min(jsDates), true);
    ending      = roundToDecade(d3.max(jsDates));

    chart = d3.select('#timeline')
              .attr('width', width)
              .attr('height', height)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)");

    xScale = d3.time.scale()
                    .nice(d3.time.year, 100)
                    .domain([beginning, ending])
                    .range([0, width - margin.right - margin.left]);

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(xScale)
                  .orient("bottom");

    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - margin.bottom) + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

    timelinePoints.buildPointPositions(Hist.TLO.range(beginning, ending));

    // Replace the points which are stacked too high with multiPoints
    timelinePoints.replaceMaxStacked();

    var points = chart.selectAll(".timeline-point").data(timelinePoints.current);
    points.enter()
      .append("image")
      .attr("class", "timeline-point")
      .attr("id", function(p) { return 'point-' + p.id; })
      .attr("x", getXPosition)
      .attr("y", getYPosition)
      .attr("cx", getXPosition)
      .attr("cy", getYPosition)
      .attr("height", pointSize)
      .attr("width", pointSize)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(p) { return p.pointImage; })
      .on("mouseover", showActiveState)
      .on("mouseout", hideActiveState)
      .on("click", setClicked);

    initContextArea();
  }

  var draw = function(range) {
    var points;

    // Create out pointPositions object
    timelinePoints.clearPointPositions();
    timelinePoints.buildPointPositions(range);
    // Replace the points which are stacked too high with multiPoints
    timelinePoints.replaceMaxStacked();

    // Remove the current points
    chart.selectAll(".timeline-point").remove();

    // Set the newly filtered points as our new data
    points = chart.selectAll(".timeline-point").data(timelinePoints.current);
    points.enter()
          .append("image")
          .attr("class", "timeline-point")
          .attr("id", function(p) { return 'point-' + p.id; })
          .attr("x", getXPosition)
          .attr("y", getYPosition)
          .attr("cx", getXPosition)
          .attr("cy", getYPosition)
          .attr("height", pointSize)
          .attr("width", pointSize)
          .attr("xlink:href", function(p) { return p.pointImage; })
          .on("mouseover", showActiveState)
          .on("mouseout", hideActiveState)
          .on("click", setClicked);
  }

  // D3 Plotting Helpers
  ///////////////////////
  var getXPosition = function(point) {
    var date = timelinePoints.pointPositions[point.id]['x'];
    return xScale(date) - (pointSize / 2);
  }

  var getYPosition = function(point) {
    // height - bottom => xAxis line
    // xAxis line - yPosMargin => Starting yPos for a 0 count point
    // starting yPos - (yPos[id] * pointSize) => final yPosition
    return height - margin.bottom - yPosMargin - (pointSize * timelinePoints.pointPositions[point.id]['y']);
  }

  // SVG Brush Helpers
  /////////////////////

  var initContextArea = function() {
    var contextWidth = 600,
        contextHeight = 30,
        contextTickSize = 30,
        contextXAxis,
        contextXScale,
        contextArea,
        context;

    contextXScale = d3.time.scale()
                           .range([0, contextWidth])
                           .domain(xScale.domain());
    contextXAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                         .scale(contextXScale)
                         .tickSize(contextTickSize)
                         .tickPadding(5)
                         .orient("bottom");

    contextArea = d3.svg.area()
                        .interpolate("monotone")
                        .x(function(d) { return contextXScale(d); })
                        .y0(contextHeight)
                        .y1(0);

    brush = d3.svg.brush()
                  .x(contextXScale)
                  .extent([beginning, ending])
                  .on("brushend", brushended);

    context = d3.select("#timeline").append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "context")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 - contextWidth / 2) + "," + (height - margin.bottom + 25) + ")");

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .call(contextXAxis);

    gBrush = context.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "brush")
                    .call(brush)
                    .call(brush.event);

    gBrush.selectAll("rect")
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
          .attr("height", contextTickSize);
  }

  var brushended = function() {
    var extent0 = brush.extent(),
        begin = extent0[0],
        end   = extent0[1],
        range = Hist.TLO.range(begin, end);

    xScale.domain([begin, end]);
    xAxis.scale(xScale);
    chart.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    timelinePoints.filterInRange(range);
    draw(range);
  }

  // Timeline Interaction Helpers
  ////////////////////////////////
  // TODO: Pull out to own module and merge with Hist.TL on init
  var initDomEventHandlers = function() {
    // Clicked away from a point handler, sets the state to inactive
    $("body").live("click", function(){
      var activePoint = $('#timeline').data('active-point'),
          activeEl;
      setUnclicked();
      if (activePoint) {
        activeEl = $('#point-' + activePoint.id)[0];
        hideActiveState.call(activeEl, activePoint);
      }
    });
  }

  var setClicked = function(point) {
    pointClicked = true;

    // Stop the event from bubbling up to body where we have a click handler to 
    // deactivate the current point. d3.event is the current event for this click
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
  }

  var setUnclicked = function() {
    pointClicked = false;
  }

  // Active State - Mousing over or clicked
  var showActiveImage = function(element, point) {
    var hoverImageUrl = point.pointImage.replace(/(.*)\.png/, "$1-hover.png");
    d3.select(element).attr("xlink:href", hoverImageUrl);
  }

  var addDescriptionToPoint = function(description) {
    if (description.length <= 200) {
      $('.regular-point .description').text(description);
    } else {
      $('.regular-point .description').text(description.substring(0, 200) + "...");
    }
  }

  var showPopup = function(element, point) {
    var d3Element = d3.select(element),
        leftPos   = parseInt(d3Element.attr('x')),
        topPos    = parseInt(d3Element.attr('y')),
        leftOffset,
        topOffset,
        popupLeft;

    // Hide both popups so we aren't showing both.
    $('.popup').hide();

    if (point.type !== 'multi') {
      // Setup the content now so we can grab the height and use it to calculate the topOffset
      $('.regular-point h3').text(point.name);
      addDescriptionToPoint(point.description);
      $('.regular-point .date').text(point.date.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY"));
      $('.regular-point a').attr('href', "/pages/" + point.vanityUrl);
      $('.regular-point').removeClass()
                         .addClass(point.type)
                         .addClass("popup")
                         .addClass("regular-point")
                         .show();
    } else {
      $('.multi-point').show();
    }

    popupHeight = $('#popup-container').height();
    leftOffset = (pointSize / 2);
    topOffset  = (pointSize / 2) + popupHeight + 11; // +11 px is for padding I think..

    // Now that we have the offset we can find the absolute position of the popup
    popupLeft = leftPos + pointSize + leftOffset + 'px';
    popupTop  = topPos + pointSize - topOffset + 'px';

    $('#popup-container').css({ left: popupLeft, top: popupTop }).show()
  }

  var showActiveState = function(point) {
    // We just moused into a point, clear the last clicked point (if any)
    setUnclicked();
    if ($('#timeline').data('active-point')) {
      // Passing null here as hideActiveImage will find the element from the given point.id
      hideActiveImage(null, $('#timeline').data('active-point'));
    }

    // Set the hover point image and configure/show the popup
    showActiveImage(this, point);
    showPopup(this, point);

    // Store the currently active point so we can deactive it later
    $('#timeline').data('active-point', point);
  }

  // Deactive State
  //////////////////
  var hideActiveImage = function(element, point) {
    // If we weren't passed the element then find it by the given point.id, otherwise select it
    d3El = element === null ? d3.select('#point-' + point.id) : d3.select(element);
    d3El.attr("xlink:href", point.pointImage);
  }

  var hidePopup = function() {
    $('#popup-container').hide();
  }

  var hideActiveState = function(point) {
    // If we are currently focusing on a point (have clicked it) then we don't 
    // want to hide the active state.
    if (!pointClicked) {
      hideActiveImage(this, point);
      hidePopup();
    }
  }

  // Public Interface
  ////////////////////
  return {

    init: function() {
      if (Hist.rawPages != null) {
        timelinePoints = pointCollection(Hist.rawPages);
        initD3Chart();
        initDomEventHandlers();
      }
    },
    config: {
      maxOfStacked: maxOfStacked
    }
  }
})();
```

**The main aspect I know I need to refactor is the way I'm handling the sorting the timeline points into approximated buckets depending on how far zoomed out/in the user is.** The majority of the code for that is in `PointCollection#buildPointPositions`. If anybody can give me a good idea on how I can improve that then that would be awesome, because as of right now it's a buggy nightmare and it's also slow as hell (I think it's \$O(N^2)\$; correct me if I'm wrong there) which isn't working with the amount of data that we have even on our staging site.

Here are a few of the other pain points I'd like to get feedback on:

- I've modeled the Timeline Objects after Douglas Crockford's "Functional Object Constructor Pattern" from *JavaScript: The Good Parts*. This is the first time I've used this pattern and I think it was a good fit for this project, but I've never heard of others using it. Any thoughts on this?
- I use moment.js and JavaScript native Date object back and forth through out my code. Looking back on it now I think I should have just picked one and stuck with it.
- Also, any comments on style or other patterns which you think I should avoid/add to my JavaScript tool-kit then please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

That's a lot of code, a small observation to start with:

```
  var rangeMemo = {};
  var pubBuildRange = function(year, mod) {
    var result = rangeMemo[year], ..snip..;
    // If we haven't seen the given year yet then continue and find the range.
    if (!result) {
      ..snip..
      // Memoize the result so we don't have to do this again.
      rangeMemo[year + "|" + mod] = result;
    }
```

If you store your result under `year + "|" + mod` but look up thru `year`, then your memoization will not ever work.

Also, consider using more object literal notation, this

```
Hist.TLO.range = function(begin, end) {
  var rangeObject = {},
      beginEpoch  = begin,
      endEpoch    = end,
      begin       = new Date(begin),
      end         = new Date(end),
      differenceInYears = end.getYear() - begin.getYear();

  var halfWayDate = function() {
    return new Date(beginEpoch + ((endEpoch - beginEpoch)/2));
  }

  var toString = function() {
    return "Range - begin: " + this.begin.toString() + " end: " + this.end.toString() + " halfWayDate: " + this.halfWayDate().toString();
  }

  // Fields
  rangeObject.begin = begin;
  rangeObject.end   = end;
  rangeObject.differenceInYears = differenceInYears;

  // Methods
  rangeObject.halfWayDate = halfWayDate;
  rangeObject.toString = toString;

  return rangeObject;
}
```

can be this:

```
Hist.TLO.range = function(beginEpoch, endEpoch) {

  return {
    begin: new Date(beginEpoch),
    end: new Date(endEpoch),
    differenceInYears: new Date(endEpoch).getYear() -  Date(beginEpoch).getYear(),

    halfWayDate : function() {
      return new Date(beginEpoch + ((endEpoch - beginEpoch)/2));
    },
    toString = function() {
      return "Range - begin: " + this.begin.toString() + " end: " + this.end.toString() + " halfWayDate: " + this.halfWayDate().toString();
    }
  };
}
```

I am still not excited about halfWayDate, why is it a function, and why is not picking up begin and end from `this`, it seems a future source of bugs.

Comment: The point on the bad memoization is a good catch. I originally was just keying off the year and then I changed my code a bit and forgot to update it.

As for the object literal notation, that does clean that object up a bit so I definitely agree with you. And another good point on halfWayDate being a function. That should just be a property that is only computed once. I'll make sure to change that.

Thanks!